# Programmatically set the terminal window size

Tags: unix, configuration, terminal, window

I program in Unix and I use a terminal client for ssh into a remote dev server. 
Now everytime I bring up a new terminal window I need to use
"Ctrl + Right Click" and reset the size to "Large" or "Huge".

I would like to setup my .profile such that this can happen programmatically.
Can you tell me how I can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

in bash, you can use the command "resize -s [rows] [cols]" 
see: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/terminalccmds.html